# Deleting a node in a sorted linked list in C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, logic

So I wrote a program for inserting, deleteing and displaying a sorted linked list. Everything runs smoothly, but when I enter an invalid number(not in the sorted linked list) for deletion, my program crashes. Here's my delete function:-

```
struct node* remove(struct node* head_ptr, int target)
{
    struct node* help_ptr, *node2del;
    help_ptr = head_ptr;
    if(help_ptr != NULL)
    {
        if(help_ptr -> data == target)
        {
            head_ptr = help_ptr -> next;
            free(help_ptr);
            return head_ptr;
        }
        while (help_ptr -> next != NULL)
        {
            if(help_ptr -> next -> data == target)
            {
                node2del = help_ptr -> next;
                help_ptr -> next = help_ptr -> next -> next;
                free(node2del);
                return head_ptr;
            }
            help_ptr = help_ptr -> next;
        }
        if(help_ptr->next->data != target)
            printf("\n%d is not in the list.",target);
    }
    return head_ptr;
}
```

[Click here](http://pastebin.com/11qVHnxG) for the full program. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` loop executes until `help_ptr->next` is `NULL`. Right after the loop, you compare `help_ptr->next->data` - but as `help_ptr->next` is `NULL`, it crashes.

The last `if` is essentially unnecessary. If the item is not found during th `while` loop, the item is not on the list.

Answer (score 0):

After traversing the whole list(as you are doing with while loop) you are again checking for the next element in the "if condition" that will certainly cause the segmentation fault.after coming out of the while loop if the element you are searching is not found you are welcome to say  "element not found".